# Where to set environment variables in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, ant

I am confused where to set enviroment variables in Ubuntu 12.04
Now I am giving like this {editing 2 files to set path variables }

## 1). gedit ~/.bashrc

## first line

export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -XX:PermSize=128M"

## 2). gedit ~/.profile

## At last

#------------------- PATH SETTINGS ------------------#

#-------- Ant Home 
ANT_HOME=/programs/apache-ant-1.8.0

#-------- Maven Home 
M2_HOME=/programs/apache-maven-3.2.1

# --------- JDK 1.6 Home 
JAVA_HOME=/programs/java/jdk1.6.0_37

# ----------JDK 1.7 Home 
#JAVA_HOME=/programs/java/jdk1.7.0_09

# ------------- Path Settings 
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin

#----------Enabling AppDynamics Viewer--------- 
PATH=$PATH:/programs/AppDynamicsLite/LiteViewer

I am getting no errors as all paths are set and i can use JAVA, JAVAC, ANT & MAVEN
I am not prefixing export command to set paths in .profile
Only heap settings are put in .bashrc

but i havenot used ANT_OPTS and MAVEN_OPTS
Hence i am confused whether they are needed or not

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about environment variables on Ubuntu. I believe it would be on-topic at [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Put the environment variables into the global /etc/environment file:

...

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0
```

...
Execute "source /etc/environment" in every shell where you want the variables to be updated:

```
$ source /etc/environment
```

Check that it works:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0
```

[Here is a other link from mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/linux/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is some info on environment variables, setting your path and where to install things that I hope is useful for you to get your environment setup.

### User specific environment variables

**.bashrc**: is specific for the *bash* shell.

**.profile**: is used by several shells, and was originally used by the bourne shell (from memory). `.profile` might not be loaded by bash if there is a `.bashrc` present. Some shells read it only if there is no shell specific configuration present.

If you happen to be using a different shell, you will need to look at how best to configure environment variables for that shell.

Note that adding to the above files only effect the user that you set them for, since they live in `/home/username/`.

Also remember to source the file again, or reload the shell so that your settings take effect. You can achieve this with something like `source .bashrc` after you edit it at the command line to avoid having to restart or reopen terminal.

### System wide environment variables

If you would like to set system wide variables, you can do that in `/etc/environment`.

### Updating your PATH

If you would like to execute java / ant / maven, etc. from the command line, or enable applications that require the `PATH` environment variable to be set correctly to work, you will also need to add the `./bin` directories to your PATH. Depending on your preference regarding system wide or user specific path settings:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

etc. in the relevant file.

### Filesystem Hierarchy Standard

A side point and entirely optional, the correct place to install java, ant, maven, etc if not from .deb's would be in `/opt`, according to the [FilesystemHierarchyStandard](https://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard)

Answer (score 0):

> Hey there, Just crawl in to this URL.

**https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables**

> It will better help you.The above URL gives all informations about
>   Environment Variable Ubuntu. ANd the above POST is updated in 3 Jan
>   2014.

Comment: hi Shihab, tanks for the link

Comment: Welcome Titus Kurian.Just **UP VOTE** for me.